# Compare hash using .htaccess file before downloading file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

TLDR: Is it possible to compare a SHA1 (or MD5) hash provided in a `GET` parameter appended to a download file's URL using an Apache .htaccess file? If the hash matches then serve the file, otherwise show permission denied error.

Here's what I am trying to do:

First, I have an Apache Web Server that I want to use to serve static files to users. The files will be PDF documents / text files / images / videos / etc. I want to deny all access to these files directly. I do not want to use a scripting language like PHP to serve these files as some are very large.

Next, I have a separate server that I will use to generate links to access these files. These links will contain a security hash key (I'm thinking SHA1). So something like (PHP as example):

`$access_token = sha1($file_name . $user_ip . $timestamp . $secret_salt);`

Then the link I will provide the user will point to the first server and look something like (as an example):

`https://www.example.com/?file=readme.txt&ip=192.168.0.1&timestamp=0000000&hash=68761328

When the user follows the link, I would like the Apache server to generate a hash from the provided parameters and the `secret_salt` and compare that to the hash that the user provided. If they match - then Apache can serve the file otherwise it should show permission denied.

In the past I've used .htaccess mod_rewrite for simple comparisons on URL params, or Cookies, etc. Does .htaccess provide this ability for comparing security hash values?

Answer (score 0):

It's not if "can .htaccess provide..." — htaccess is just a config file, but unlike the main apache config which is read when apache launches, htaccess is read every time the folder is accessed.

As such, the first question is, what version Apache are you running? Versions 2.4 added IF/ELSEIF/ELSE logic and a new expression syntax.

The next question is, can you do all this with just rewrites? You need to create the hashes — there is some hash generation capability in the expression syntax that might allow this. It might need to be a combination of PHP/Java/ap_exp.

**htaccess or conf**

If you have access to the main config files, it's often better performance wise to to put all your rewrites there, as the htaccess file is read every time a folder is accessed and thus has a minor performance hit.

**Some Ideas**

I was working on an anti-hot-link strategy similar to what you describe before I got sidetracked with another project. You might want to google anti-hot-linking, as there are a lot of solutions.

One of the stumbles I came across was how long should a hash or download UL be valid? And what should cause it to expire? Because if it is to have a long enough life for practical purposes, there is the potential to need multiple hashes to be compared for various degrees of expiration.

And of course, you have to expire the hash - if it's a persistent hash, all the user needs to do is use that same hash in their hotlink. At the same time you don't want to inconvenience users by making the expirations interfere with downloading.

**So some thoughts I had along the way:**

- Use a cookie to control expiration and access to the file server
- Create a symlink for each requested file, and use the hash for the symlink name, then use a cron job to delete all symlinks that are more that n hours old.
- Use odd/even hours (odd hash expires at the top of every odd hour, user gets an odd or even hash depending on the hour they request, so they always have at least one full hour to complete the download).
- Use a reverse proxy file server (behind your firewall) along with some of these.

I personally was doing most of this in PHP, but I think Apache Expressions could handle a lot of it.

While this isn't a direct answer (some assembly required) I hope it was useful to you.

Comment: That's very useful information and your ideas are good ones, some are very close to my thought process as well - I'll check out the Apache docs to see how close I can get with expressions. Thank you :)